# Raise agent and increase z-position while being moved

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I want to transport an Agent with the `moveTo`, `seize` and `release` blocks and while being transported by the resource (automatic guided vehicle), I want the agent to lie on top of the resource, so being raised by a few pixels.

I guess some function like `setOffsets` on entering the `seize` block and leaving the `release` block would do the job, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the "onEnter" code box of a "Seize" block, you can set the z-position of each incoming agent using `agent.setZ(10)` which will raise it by 10 pixels. If it should be "dropped" again, use `agent.setZ(0)` wherever appropriate.

hope that helps

Comment: I would rephrase it to "...which will raise it to z=10px..." since it isn't a displacement but rather an absolute position you define.